# How to use auto filter in excel using macros

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I'm trying to do an auto filter function in excel using macro. So far I have this:

```
Sub Macroforqueues()

ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AC$8312").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=Array( _
    "=*russia*", "=*hungary*", "=*Brazil*", "=*armenia*", "=*belarus*", "=*belgium*", "=*georgia*", "=*Vietnam*", "=*latvia*", "=*moldova*", "=*netherlands*", "=*poland*", "=*United Kingdom*", "=*uzbekistan*"), Operator:=xlFilterValues

                 End Sub
```

I want to filter out using the "like" function, and it is working until I only have 2 countries but as soon as I add more I'm always getting 0 cells back.

Can you advise what is wrong?

Comment: You can only use wildcards with 2 criteria. This has been asked several times before here.

Comment: so how would you approach this problem then?